# Wordpress 記事投稿直後にバックグラウンドで処理を行いたい(並列処理？)

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpressで記事投稿直後にバックグラウンドで処理を行いたいのですが、
どうやら wp_schedule_single_event がきちんとトリガーされていないようです。
以下のコードのどこが間違っているか、ご指摘頂ければ幸いです！

```
// functions.php

add_action('save_post', 'registerMyCron');

function registerMyCron(){
  wp_schedule_single_event(time(), 'myCronAction');
}

add_action('myCronAction', 'doSomething');

function doSomething(){
  // 何らかの処理...
}
```

Comment: 回答者や検索エンジンはタグも見ているでしょうから、[あえてタイトルにタグのようなものを含める必要はない](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2421/8000)です。ただ、このサイトだとWordpressに詳しい回答者は少ない気もするので、ja.wordpress.orgのフォーラム等を利用したほうが的確な回答が得られるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

WordPress Codex では [`wp_schedule_single_event()`](https://wpdocs.osdn.jp/%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%83%AA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9/wp_schedule_single_event) について次のように書かれています。

> 指定した時刻に WordPress のコア機能によって一度だけ実行されるフック（アクション）を登録します。そのアクションは誰かが WordPress サイトを訪れたときに予定した時刻を過ぎていれば実行されます。

ですから、現在時刻+n秒と指定したところでその時間に実行される保証はないですし、現在時刻を指定したらすぐさま実行されるわけではありません。

`spawn_cron()` 関数を呼ぶことですぐにスケジュールの確認と実行が行われるようなので、これを呼び出すと直ちに実行できるのではないでしょうか。

```
function registerMyCron(){
  wp_schedule_single_event(time(), 'myCronAction');
  spawn_cron();
}
```

私自身はWordPressに詳しくないので、この方法が適切なのかどうかはわかりませんが…。

参考 [WordPressプラグインの重い処理をバックグランドで非同期に実行する方法 | ゆっくりと…](http://tokkono.cute.coocan.jp/blog/slow/index.php/wordpress/wordpress-background-cron/)

Comment: アドバイスありがとう御座います。
投稿後に投稿画面にアクセスすることになるので、Timestampがtime()とすると投稿直後に実施されるはずかなと思います。

ところで、その後問題は解決しました。
wp-config.phpに `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON',true);` を追記しても動かず、その後Apacheを再起動したら、なぜか突然動き始めました！

Comment: @gurigurico 解決して良かったですね。もしよければ、検索などでこの質問にたどり着いた人のためにご自身で回答を書いて解決マークをつけてもらえませんか。